# How to add constraints to make sure a customer can only purchase a certain number of product - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I am trying to write a Check to make sure that a customer can only buy 10 of a certain product type (smartphone) and 4 of another product type(tv), and buy another product only during morning(before 12:30). The table is

> invoice(PK invoice_no, FK product, amount, customer_name,time, FK opening_time )

`Check (amount >10)` would check the amount but I want to limit only a few types of products. Also product type isn't in my invoice table, should I add that to the table or can I join another table (Product) in check?

Comment: Except for foreign key constraints, all other constraint types are restricted to the table itself and cannot reference another table.

Comment: But... instead of a constraint you could try using a trigger on insert. Not sure, though, but it's worth exploring.

Comment: @TheImpaler, triggers can delete or update data, but would that work like a check? Would that make an error message saying you can't add this data or would that add all the other data and just delete the specific row? Also assume that I added product type to the table, how would it work? Is check syntax same as any query?

Comment: Seems you have a normalization issue. First off do not put product type on the invoice. Its "already there" via FK product. (I assume product type is attribute of product). It would seem the amount limit and time_of_day restrictions are attributes of product not invoice. Perhaps even a product_restrictions table. That way changes or additions become a simple table update, and give ability track the change. Also you get simple enforcement from the Business Rules level of the application.  Additionally, why does invoice have customer name instead of a FK to customer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this kind of validation / restriction is better fit to your application's business  level rather then your data / database level

Comment: Could something like `check (amount > 10 AND product ilike '%phone%')` work?

Comment: @arthionne, as I said, in my opinion, this kind of restriction should not be database level. If you set it to 10 now, and tomorow you chance your mind and want to limit to 5... If you haver a database level restriction, your data would be considered inconsistent, and its not true. Keep responsabilities separate, the business level and data level..